# horizontally Aligning dynamically created widgets qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, alignment, qlineedit, qlabel

The following code is used by me to dynamically generate a QLabel and QLineEdit(vertically) based on a QStringList(named newList) !

```
for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++)
{
      QlineEdit *a=new QLineEdit();
      QLabel *b= new QLabel();

      ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(a);
      ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(b);

      b->setText(newList[i]);
}
```

Both the labels and line edits are generated and the items of the string list is depicted in the labels!But the problem I face is that label corresponding to each line edit is not alligned horizontally with that line edit! How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the LineEdit and Label in a QFrame and than put the QFrame in the vertical Layout. Or you use a horizontal layout for LineEdit and Label and put this to the vertical layout.

edit: (not tested and only write quickly!)

```
for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++)
{
      QFrame *f = new QFrame();  
      QlineEdit *a=new QLineEdit( f );
      QLabel *b= new QLabel( f );


      ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(f);

      b->setText(newList[i]);
}
```

[Exampels for different ways in comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AbZ6.png)